# Problem with RCU when configuring Oracle 12C Forms

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracle12c

I have installed oracle 12c and weblogic server installed.

I have configured web logic server and it is up and running.

Next step is to configure Repository Creation utility and to proceed with Forms configuration.

I opted "Prepare Scripts for system Load" because we do not have sysdba permission users.

How to configure RCU without knowing the username and password?

Note:I have the host and service details.

Refer the screenshots.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LaFT.png)

[image]

Thanks
Sudha

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Username and password are obligatory.

Default username is `SYS`; if you use it, role must be `SYSDBA`. Other usernames would use `NORMAL` role.

If you don't know those credentials, ask your DBA; they know *everything* about it.

Comment: Thank for your reply.They wont share sysdba details,there is an other option to create scripts for DBA to run later.Is there any other ways to do so?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think that there's another option you could use.

Comment: only sysdba can do this or other users with grant permissions?

Comment: It depends on user you use; SYS must be a SYSDBA. Others don't (and probably aren't).